# Moving in a shuttle-like manner, while advancing forward

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single-word equivalent of moving in a shuttle-like manner while advancing forward, like Corker Spaniels do?

I initially contemplated using the word "to shuttle" but for me it has connotations of moving back and forth rather than from side to side while advancing. The point is in searching terrain in this manner.

Comment: I think you mean "*Cocker* Spaniels".

Comment: Though it's not clear what is so special about their walk.

Comment: Don't you mean *shuffle*?

Comment: Did shuttle come to you from *weaving*?  What other ways can you describe this motion before you hit a wall?

Comment: You can *snake back and forth* over the yard hunting for the scent.

Comment: I think 'moving shuttle-like' is enough; manner is redundant.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. When I read _to shuttle_, I think of a straight line with no side-to-side action at all (i.e. airport shuttle, or space shuttle). I don't think of weaving, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @IanMacDonald A loom has a shuttle, so as it's drawing the weft thread across the warp threads, it's advancing via a zig-zag motion.

Comment: @user888379 Yeah, I understand that. It's just not what I think of, especially when talking about movement.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Well the OP could have gone with boustrophedonic, instead of shuttle-like...

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the dog is actually doing, if it is zigzagging over a large area, then it is "quartering [the ground]"

> OED 9. a. transitive. **To range or traverse (ground, etc.) in every direction; said esp. of dogs in search of game, .... Also intransitive: to range to and fro in this way; to move from point to point.**
>
> 1873   G. C. Davies Mountain, Meadow & Mere x. 76   *The hounds quartered to and fro.*
>
> 1888   Antipod. Notes 6   *Two boats are..quartering the sea, as a..pointer quarters a turnip-field.*
>
> 1991   Sporting Dog Jan. 14/1   *Watching trained dogs quarter the moors in search of the elusive grouse*.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *zigzag*: to proceed by sharp turns in alternating directions.

There's also the nautical term *tack*. A ship which tacks is going alternately left and right in order to advance, but *tack* also implies that it is turning into the wind in order to do so, and that wouldn't be necessarily be true of dogs.